# Strong Uniform Total Order vs Weak Uniform Total Order

Tags: distributed-systems

The definition for SUTO and WUTO is the following:

Suto

> If some process TODelivers some message m before message mʹ, then a process TODelivers mʹonly after it has TODelivered m.

And for WUTO

> If process p and process q both TODdeliver messages m and mʹ, then p TODelivers m before mʹ if and only if q TODdelivers m before mʹ.

I have a hard time getting my head around this. For me, both of them sounds the same...

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Consider for example two processes $p_1$ and $p_2$, with $p_1$ that delivers in this order $m$ and then $m'$.

In SUTO, $p_2$ will either deliver $m-m'$ as $p_1$ did, or it won't deliver $m'$ at all.
But why?

Because if $p_2$ will deliver, for example, $m - m'' - m'$, then every process can deliver $m'$ only after $m''$.
This means that once $p_1$ and $p_2$ don't deliver the same messages, the  following  messages delivered by $p_1$ and $p_2$ must be disjoint.

In WUTO instead it's possible to have $p_1$ that delivers $m - m'$ and $p_2$ that delivers $m - m'' - m'$.

This example is taken from Baldoni, Cimmino and Marchetti, [A classification of total order specifications and its application to fixed sequencer-based implementations](http://midlab.diag.uniroma1.it/articoli/jpdc-revised.pdf).